# Can more than one author be listed in the byline?

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone v4.1.2, and I'd like to know if there a way to include more than one author in the by line of a page?  I have two authors listed in ownership, but only one author is listed in the byline.

I'd like the byline to look something like this:

by First Author and Second Author  —    last modified  Jan 11, 2012 01:53 PM   — History

UPDATE - Thanks everyone for your replies.  I managed to bungle my way through this (I've never used tal before).  I edited plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline as suggested by Giaccamo, and managed to learn a bit about tal along the way.  Here is the code that does what I needed (this replaces the existing tal:creator construct):

```
    <span>
         by
       <span class="documentCreators"
           tal:condition="context/Creators"
           tal:repeat="creator context/Creators"
           i18n:translate="text_creators">
          <span tal:define="cond1 repeat/creator/start; cond2 repeat/creator/end"
              tal:condition="python: not cond1 and not cond2" >, </span>
          <span tal:define="cond1 repeat/creator/start; cond2 repeat/creator/end"
               tal:condition="python: not cond1 and cond2" > and </span>
          <tal:i18n i18n:translate="label_by_author">
          <a href="#"
             tal:attributes="href string:${context/@@plone_portal_state/navigation_root_url}/author/${creator}"
             tal:content="creator"
             tal:omit-tag="python:view.author() is None"
             i18n:name="author">Roland Barthes</a>
          </tal:i18n>
      </span>
    </span>
```

This puts the userid on the byline instead of the full name.  I tried to get the full name, but after some time without success I decided I could live with userid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to browse more than one author you'll need a little bit of coding:

That piece of page is called `viewlets`.

That specific viewlet is called `plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline`.

You can use [z3c.jbot](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot) to override the viewlet template. Take a look at [this howto](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/z3c.jbot) for usage. Another option is to customize the template through-the-web following [this tutorial](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/elements/visibleelements/plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try this.  It looks a bit intimidating, but I've never been shy about trying.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the contributors- instead of the owners-field. they are listed by default in the docByLine. hth, i

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that all contributors were listed.  I've never used contributors before.  I'd like to have them in the byline though.  But I can probably borrow some of the code that handles the contributors so this is helpful!

Comment: css should do it, sth like: .documentAuthor { display: none; }
.documentContributors { float: left; }
.documentContributors:after { content: '–'; margin: 0 0.5em 0 0.25em; }